# How can I buy stock in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How can I buy stock in Stack Overflow? Who should I contact in order to make a purchase?

Comment: Stock in SO can only be purchased in millions of shares, using a million unicorn bill.

Comment: @Tim can I write a check? I have my unicorn horn quill.

Comment: What's the exchange rate between bacon and unicorns?

Comment: Not helping people, not helping....but funny

Comment: I've got a super awesome software thingy you can invest in.  Pls give me your monies kthx.

Comment: I am sure if you send money to Jeff, he will tell what an awesome person you are. Invest in your self esteem!  (Serious answer:  SO is a private company like @Rafe mentioned in his answer)

Answer (score 9):

You can't, it's a privately held company (you could probably invest, but not in any small amount).

As for who you can contact, if SO ever goes public (only Jeff and Joel can know that), you'd just call your broker.

Answer (score 4):

You can approach Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc., located in New York, and ask them if you can invest. If they are interested you will need to figure out a valuation that makes sense. They are a funded company so it wont be cheap to get in. The other alternative is to watch the second market sites like secondmarket.com or sharespost.com and when someone is looking to unload shares jump on it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that if you have enough money then Jeff & Joel et al will be pleased to take some off you. It may take a bit to convince them though.

Comment: Somebody offered them $100K live on the podcast - they refused

Comment: Thats because it was live

Comment: @user were you there?

Comment: I see, and how do I contact Jeff and Joel?

Comment: Jeff reads meta a lot --  he'll probably see this

Comment: probably???? I need a definitely.

Comment: @user I'm sure Jeff will read this, but I'm not sure what you want from him; Rafe already pointed out that they're not publicly traded

Comment: Doing a private trade would be the logic choice. Hence why contacting him is needed.

Comment: @user That seems...unlikely. But you can always e-mail team@stackoverflow.com about it

Comment: so Jeff himself, will not respond to me? I will not disclose how much I wish to invest here, but I will say it could be interesting.

Comment: Go to New York, find their office, and make it rain! Or...http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/about-me.html -> "How can I contact you?"

Comment: @user: i find it curious that despite all the jokes flying around about your intentions you are still serious.... what do you know that we don't?

Comment: I find it  bizzare that people wouldnt want to invest in SO. I just want to contact Jeff is all.

Comment: @user156375 hey, I want to invest in Valve, too... but Gabe Newell makes too much money to give up any ownership. I suspect SO is the same way.